# Checking data enter by user with parameter set, sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm doing a checking from data enter by user with data that already set.
As example, data save in sqlite is 60-80. If user input is 88. i want to check the user input which is 88 with data 60-80, so that i can come out with appropriate advice

Help me.

i did like this

```
public String getRangeFromUserInput(int b1, int b2, int b3, int a1, int a2, int a3) {

    if 
       (((70<b1<<100)||(70<b2<<100)||(70<b3<<100))&&((70<a1<<135)||(70<a2<<135)||(70<a3<<135)))
        Toast.makeText(GlucoseAdd.this, "Your glucose level is at normal range", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else if 
       (((50<b1<<60)||(50<b2<<60)||(50<b3<<60))&&((135<a1<<180)||(135<a2<<180)||(135<a3<<180)))
        Toast.makeText(GlucoseAdd.this, "You need to start diet. The diet should " +
                "also be low in fat and high in dietary fibre. Regular exercise " +
                "is important in maintaining balanced blood glucose levels.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else if 
        (((b1<50)||(b2<50)||(b3<50))&&((180<a1<<200)||(180<a2<<200)||(180<a3<<200)))
        Toast.makeText(GlucoseAdd.this, "You are in danger state.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
}
```

but when i enter data all prompt out the first one.. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data stored in your DB table is in the format of string i.e. 60-80
So you'll need to convert the user input value (for ex. 88) into i.e. 80-100 using the following code:

```
public String getRangeFromUserInput(String userInput) {
    return getRangeFromUserInput(Integer.parseInt(userInput));
}

public String getRangeFromUserInput(int userInput) {

    if (userInput >= 60 && userInput < 80)
        return "60-80";
    else if (userInput >= 80 && userInput < 100)
        return "80-100";
    // ...more range checks

    return null;
}
```

Now, use the output of the method getRangeFromUserInput() which is a string (for ex. 80-100) in the where clause of your query as follows:

```
String where = "range = '" + getRangeFromUserInput("88") + "'";
```

Assuming the column name is *range* in your table. If the query returns a row then you can read the advice corresponding to the range using

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("advice"))
```

Assuming the column name is *advice* in your table.

Comment: but my data in sqlite is in string

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem since getRangeFromUserInput() returns a String. See my edited answer.